# append method will not work in jquery

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have create JSON. and I have working in jquery mobile, This will not work in my code. Code is executed but element will not append.

```
var serviceName= [{..},{..},{..}]

    $('#service_select').empty();
    $('#service_select').append('<select name="day" id="day">');
    for(var i = 0; i < serviceName.length; i++ ){
        $('#service_select').append('<option value=" '+ serviceName[i].name+'">'+serviceName[i].name+'</option>');
    }
    $('#service_select').append('</select>');
```

html code

```
<div id="service_select"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ,Close select tags and append it to service_select DIV ,Then append option to it ,Because evenif you dont specify,jQuery creates closing tags immediately for  if you dont specify

//NEW CODE just copy paste

```
<script>
var serviceName= [1,3,5,7,9];

$('#service_select').empty();
$("#service_select").append('<select name="day" id="day"></select>');
for(var i = 0; i < serviceName.length; i++ ){
$("#service_select select").append(new Option(serviceName[i], serviceName[i]));
}
</script>
```

Check jsfiddeel http://jsfiddle.net/TfM9S/

Comment: Pratik, you don't have to continue helping him if you don't feel it is worth your time. Also, it's spelled "jsfiddle", not "jsfiddeel". Mohaideen, please don't drag answerers out of the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the first append() creates the closing `</select>`, too. jQuery will not create invalid html.

try this:

```
$('#service_select').empty();
$('#service_select').append('<select name="day" id="day"></select>');
for(var i = 0; i < serviceName.length; i++ ){
    $('#service_select select').append('<option value=" '+ serviceName[i].name+'">'+serviceName[i].name+'</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to use this form:

```
var $selectElement = $('<select>', {
   'name': 'day',
   'id': 'day'
});
for(var i = 0; i < serviceName.length; i++ ){
      var $optionEl = $('<option>', {
        'value': serviceName[i].name,
        'text': serviceName[i].name
      });
      $selectElement.append($optionEl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works Properly

```
var serviceName = [{..},{..}]


$(document).on("pageinit","#anotherPageId", function(){
    $('#service_select').empty();
    $('#service_select').append('<select name="service" id="service"></select>');
    for (var i = 0; i < serviceName.length; i++) {
        $('#service_select select').append('<option value=" ' + serviceName[i].name + '">' + serviceName[i].name + '</option>');
    }
});
```